# wxWidgets issue using wxClientDc

Tags: wxwidgets

i'm be beginning to use wxWidgets in a project and i'm using wxClientDc to draw on a image. I created a class that inherits wxStaticBitmap adding my properties and drawing over it. To clear the image i'm setting the background as the same wxBitmap that i used in MY image:

```
    //that is my class
    class myImage : public wxStaticBitmap { 
    public: 
        wxBitmap frame;  //imagem
        myImage(wxWindow* parent, wxWindowID id, wxPoint pos, wxSize size, wxBitmap frame);
    private:
        void redesenha();
        void mouseUp(wxMouseEvent& event);
        void mouseDown(wxMouseEvent& event); 
        void mouseMove(wxMouseEvent& event); 
        wxDECLARE_EVENT_TABLE();
    };
    myImage::myImage(wxWindow* parent, wxWindowID id, wxPoint pos, wxSize size, wxBitmap frame): wxStaticBitmap(parent, id, frame, pos, size){
        this->frame = frame;
    }
    
    //that is my function to clear my image
    void myFrame::onClickClear(wxCommandEvent& event)
    {
        wxClientDC dc(myImg);
        dc.SetBackground(wxBrush(myImg->frame)); //frame is a wxBitmap type
        dc.Clear();
    }
```

The issue is that works in my laptop but when my friend download and compile it's doesn't work in his laptop.

Comment: usual stanza - 1. OS? 2 OS version? 3 wx version? 4 did you build wx dynamically or statically? And it goes for both you and your friend machine. On top of that - define `. doesn't work`. Throws an exception? Retruns an error? Produces wrong results? If yes - which operation? Did you also look at wxOverlay?

Comment: @Igor we are using windows 10 and wxWidgets 3.1.4 build the screen dynamically. Our machines have been configured with the same version of wxWidgets.

Sorry, i forgot to explain why does'n work. On my friend's laptop when the Clear function is called the image is filled with black instead the Bitmap but when he set a color to backgrount it work correctly.

Comment: and I presume you use the same compiler and same compilation options for both the library and the application? Did you try to handle wxEVT_ERASEBACKGROUND? Do you have wxEVT_PAINT handler?

Comment: @Igor i don't have. what should i put in these events?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to "clear" a `wxStaticBitmap`, just assign a solid bitmap with the given colour.

More generally speaking, you shouldn't try to draw over the native controls (such as `wxStaticBitmap`) and you shouldn't use `wxClientDC` at all as drawing is only supported from `wxEVT_PAINT` handlers on many modern systems (e.g. macOS).